# Trying to get hour 00:00:00 of a specific day, getting relative time instead

Tags: php, date, time, unix-timestamp

To be very brief, I'm trying to get a timestamp of a specific day (the beginning of the month) at a very specific time (00:00:00).  I'm then trying to get that value into a unix time stamp used to search the database.  The day is working fine, but when I check the time stamp it's setting itself to a relative time to the current time.  For example, right now it is 8:55 am here and the output I'm receiving is 1:56 pm (UTC).  I want 00:00 UTC.  Here's the code I'm working with.

```
$from = "$month/1/$year";
$to = $month+1."/1/$year";
$fromDate = date_create("$from");
$toDate = date_create("$to");
$fromDate->setTime(0,0,0);
$toDate->setTime(0,0,0);
$from = strtotime($fromDate);
$to = strtotime($toDate);
```

here's the output:

$from = 1464789100

$to = 1467381099

**edit: solved**

My tables were messed up. I had some messed up data that was throwing everything off that I admittedly caused for testing purposes (because forgetting that your testing cases exist is always a good idea). Thanks all for your help.

Comment: did you try `$from = "$month/1/$year 00:00:00";`?

Comment: Yes.  Still same problem.  I'm getting 2:06 pm (because time has passed; the time isn't setting itself statically, it's dynamically setting it based on the current time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i:s', '05/02/2015 00:00:00');
var_dump($date->format('U'));
/* Add 1 month to date */
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
var_dump($date->format('U'));
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, ended up with the same result.  After being converted into a unix timestamp via strtotime() I'm still getting dynamic time instead of a static 00:00:00 on that specific date, so unfortunately your answer did not work.

Comment: @dmcoding `$date->format('U');` it's return date in unix timesamp format. You don't need to use additional function `strtotime()`

Comment: This does indeed give a static time.  I greatly appreciate it.  Answer accepted, I'll edit my question with your added answer.  I didn't realize that using 'strtotime()' would screw everything up so bad.  Thank you so much.